# How do we prove that hypercharge is different for singlets and doublets?

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction, electroweak

I am trying to teach myself about the standard model and I am stumped by this point.

I understand that:

1. When picking an U(1) generator for SU(2)xU(1), any multiple of the identity will do ($YI_n$)
2. The U(1) generator doesn't have to be the same fo singlets and doublets since this happens in different representations. So we have $Y_L I_2$ for doublets and $Y_R$ (1x1 matrix, so essentially a scalar) for singlets.

There is one degree of freedom, so it is conventional to pick $Y_L=-1$. But how do we prove that $Y_R=-2$?

I have seen it sketched in two ways:

1. We find in the doublet representation that $Q=T_3+Y_L I_2/2$ matches what we expect from an electric charge operator. Then we use the fact that for the electron singlet, $Q=-1$ and $T_3=0$ to get the result. I'm not sure that's very rigorous.
2. I've seen an allusion somewhere that the bosons transform differently (a priori) under U(1) transformation of doublets and singlets, so we need to fix the ratio to ensure they in fact undergo the same transformation. (And we were dealing with singlet and n-uplets, the ratio would be n, etc.)

Comment: Which bosons are your talking about? not the gauge bosons, all inert under Y.  The Higgs?  Where is "somewhere". Can you be more precise?   In nay case, (1) is the mainstream explanation. What type of "rigor" are you seeking?

Comment: Thank you, I was talking of the $B_\mu$ bosons (are those inert under Y?) By 'rigor' I mean: can we deduce the relationship between the U(1) coupling constant for singlets and n-uplets, even without any prior knowledge of electric charges and other empirical inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SM was constructed empirically by "hit-or-miss", so (1) is the rationale, and no inconsistencies were detected. In particular, by the weak mimicking of the Gell-Mann–Nishijima formula, $Q= I_3+Y/2$, since the average weak Isospin for both right singlets and left doublets vanishes, the weak hypercharge  is pegged to twice the average electric charge of all multiplets. (This [includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge#Definition) the Higgs doublet, whose lower component picks up the v.e.v., so must have the charge of the vacuum, namely, 0.)

This *Y* must be broken spontaneously to [conspire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle) with $I_3$ to yield a massless photon and a massive Z boson. The three original non-abelian gauge bosons must be inert under *Y*, since the SU(2) ones correspond to generators commuting with its U(1) one; while the $B_\mu$ gauges this U(1), abelian, so it does not couple to itself, (like the photon in QED).

The whole structure is consistent, with no slop, i.e., all assignments are fixed. After its construction, the SM was also found to be [free of chiral anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_(physics)#Anomaly_cancellation), within each generation,
$$
\sum_{all ~doublets}\!\!\!\! \mathrm{Tr} ~T^a T^b Y \propto \delta^{ab}  \sum_{all ~doublets} Y=\sum_{all ~doublets} Q =0 ~.
$$
The right singlets have no weak isospin, so their anomaly automatically vanishes.

$$\phantom{a}$$
$$\phantom{a}$$

<sub>If they can get you asking the wrong questions, they don't have to worry about answers. [Thomas Pynchon, "Gravity's Rainbow"]</sub>